# How to make a moving div restricted in an outside div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, keydown, key-events

So I have a div you move with your arrow keys, but how do I make it so it can't go outside the "border div"?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).keydown(function(e) {
      switch (e.which) {
      case 37: // Left
        $("#cube").css("left", $("#cube").offset().left - 101);
        break;
      case 38: // Up
        $("#cube").css("top", $("#cube").offset().top - 11);
        break;
      case 39: // Right
        $("#cube").css("left", $("#cube").offset().left - 97);
        break;
      case 40: // Down
        $("#cube").css("top", $("#cube").offset().top - 7);
        break;
      }
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SfKHN/

Comment: Your code will be cleaner and will run faster if you use a global: var  $cube = $("#cube");

Comment: @user2291675 I have added a solution to your issue take a look?

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:- I tested in FF and Chrome and seems to be fine....

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Zv3Ca/)**

Probably this is not completely perfect but you can build on it. Key here is to get the margins of the parent right and make sure the cube's left/right/top/bottom doesn't go beyond it. Border width also should be considered. Another thing is your Step should be a multiple of its width/height(as it is a square)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        var cube = $("#cube");
        var leftMargin = 0;
        var rightMargin = $('#outside').position().left + $('#outside').width() - cube.width();
        var topMargin =0;
        var bottomMargin = $('#outside').position().top + $('#outside').height() - cube.height();
        switch (e.which) {
        case 37: // Left
                var newLeft = parseInt(cube.position().left - 50);
               if(leftMargin <= newLeft)
                {
                    cube.css("left", newLeft);
                }
            break;
        case 38: // Up
                var newTop = parseInt(cube.position().top - 50);
                if(topMargin <= newTop)
                {
                    cube.css("top",newTop);
                }
            break;
        case 39: // Right
                var newRight = (cube.position().left + 50);
                 if(rightMargin > newRight)
                {
                    cube.css("left", newRight);
                }
            break;
        case 40: // Down
                var newBottom = parseInt(cube.position().top + 50);
                if(bottomMargin > newBottom)
                {
                    cube.css("top", newBottom);
                }
            break;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You add simple if statements to make sure you haven't passed the border. Here's an example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        switch (e.which) {

            case 38: // Up
                if( ( $("#cube").offset().top - 11 ) >= 0 )
                    $("#cube").css("top", $("#cube").offset().top - 11);
                break;

            case 40: // Down
                if( ( $( "#cube" ).offset( ).top - 7 ) < ( 400 - 50 ) )
                    $("#cube").css("top", $("#cube").offset().top - 7 );
                break;
        }
    });
});
```

You'd make similar changes to the left and right arrows

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $out  = $('#outside'),
        w     = $out.width(),
        $cube = $('#cube'),
        cw    = $cube.outerWidth();

    $(document).up(function (e) {
        switch (e.which) {
            case 37:
                $cube.css('left', function (_, left) {
                    left = parseInt(left, 10);
                    if (left !== 0) return left - cw;
                });
                break;
            case 38:
                $cube.css('top', function (_, top) {
                    top = parseInt(top, 10);
                    if (top !== -1) return top - cw;
                });
                break;
            case 39:
                $cube.css('left', function (_, left) {
                    left = parseInt(left, 10);
                    if (left + cw < w) return left + cw;
                });
                break;
            case 40:
                $cube.css('top', function (_, top) {
                    top = parseInt(top, 10);
                    if (top !== 349) return top + cw;
                });
                break;
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QmBNC/